# Items added with Append arent recognized by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I am dynamically (jquery append) adding images to the div, however the dynamically added images wont be recognized by my querySelectorAll.

**Adding Images:**

```
   $('#images').append('<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4 thumb"><img draggable="true" class="img-thumbnail" src="'+val.path+'"alt="Another alt text" width="300"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger imagedel" data-id="'+val.id+'"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></div>');
```

**The Selector:**

```
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumbnail');
```

The script works on existing items on the page, as soon as i try to add an item which has been added with `.append()` it doesnt recognize it.

Also, i tried another selector: `var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');`

**The complete code:**

```
$.getJSON('/api/getimages', null, function(e){
  //$('#images').empty();
  $.each(e.images, function(key, val){
    $('#images').append('<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-4 thumb"><img draggable="true" class="img-thumbnail" src="'+val.path+'"alt="Another alt text" width="300"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger imagedel" data-id="'+val.id+'"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></div>');
  });
});

function dragAndDropSupported () {
    return 'draggable' in document.createElement('span');
}

function handleDragStart(e) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
    this.classList.add('img_dragging');
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; 

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over'); 
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging'));

    var img = document.querySelector('#images .img_dragging');
    var _canvasWidth = document.getElementById("canvas-container").clientWidth;
    var _canvasHeight = document.getElementById("canvas-container").clientHeight;
    var _scale = 1;

    if (img.width > img.height && img.width > (_canvasWidth-200) ){ _scale = (_canvasWidth-200)/img.width; }
    if (img.height > img.width && img.height > (_canvasHeight-200) ){ _scale = (_canvasHeight-200)/img.height;}

    var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
        scaleY: _scale/4,
        scaleX: _scale/4,
        left: e.layerX,
        top: e.layerY
    });
    canvas.add(newImage);

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
}

if (dragAndDropSupported() === true) {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumbnail');
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });

    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
} else {
    alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
}
```

I expect the image to be placed into my canvas container. Now it returns a type error `TypeError: img is null` on my dynamically added images.

Comment: Isn't this `[].forEach` supposed to be `images.forEach`?

Comment: They both seem to have the same effect